# how to remove the duplicated code for the code example in java?

Tags: java

```
package org.test.toolkit.file;

public interface FileType {

    public enum Image implements FileType {

        JPG;

        public String toString() {  //duplicated code
            return "." + super.toString().toLowerCase();
        };
    }

    public enum Office implements FileType {

        DOC;

        public String toString() {
            return "." + super.toString().toLowerCase();
        };
    }

    public enum PlainText implements FileType {

        TXT;

        public String toString() {  //duplicated code
            return "." + super.toString().toLowerCase();
        };
    }

}
```

How to efficiently remove duplicate code. Perhaps i should consider using a static method defined in other class object? Or is there a better way to solve my problem?

```
    public String toString() {
        return "." + super.toString().toLowerCase();
    };
```

Comment: How to remove duplicated question?

Answer (score 3):

```
public enum Type
{
  Image,Document,Text;
}
public enum FileType
{
   DOC(Type.Document), JPG(Type.Image),GIF(Type.Image),TXT(Type.Text);
   private Type type;
   private FileType(Type t)
   {
      this.type=t;
   }
   public Type getType()
   {
      return type;
   }
   public String toString()
   {
       return "." + super.toString().toLowerCase();
   }
}
```

?

Comment: you can then also associate the type of file as a separate enum and use DOC(Type.Document),JPG(Type.Image),TXT(Type.Text);

Comment: At first , I use your stratage, but I if I need add PNG/BMP, it will belong to image similar with JPG. So I need take this method to split types. But after the types splited, the duplicated code generated.

Comment: At the beginning of design, I use your stratage, but I if I need add PNG/BMP, it will belong to image similar with JPG. So I need take this method to split types. But after the types splited, the duplicated code generated.

Comment: I check your code again, your code is reasonable. but it is harder to use due to the case with huge accounts sub types  existed.